# Downloading webpages programmatically

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html

I need to download certain web pages from a web site for my research. I tried to download them using Darcy Wripper, WinHTTrack and C# WebClient method. It happens so that some of the pages get downloaded while (majority) others throw error. For example I have copied this error from Darcy Wripper.

> 27    http://www.dawn.com/news/515958/animadversion-only-the-globes-looked-golden Error   N/A N/A 500 0   403
>   - Request Aborted 11  http://www.dawn.com/news/813115/flavours-of-culture Error   N/A N/A 500 0   403

The same webpage opens in Firefox (sometimes there is an error that we are in maintenance, but next try opens the page).
My question: Is there a method in C# to download such problematic pages? I also tried to look for a Firefox Wrapper for .Net with no luck. I was under the impression that maybe a I can open these pages in Firefox using an array of links one by one and save them from a command line program.
Any help or insight in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to download specific pages using c#/.net, right? Here is some code to get you started:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.dawn.com/news/515958/animadversion-only-the-globes-looked-golden");
var response = request.GetResponse();
string content = null;
using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    content = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
}
/* do cool stuff with the content */
```

Comment: Thanks a lo.t. I tried Darcy Wripper again and again. Downloaded enough pages that were sufficient for my purpose. There seemed to be a problem with the server as it was not responding rightly to a number of downloading methods.